What is the repulsive force that keeps protons and neutrons apart?
The strong nuclear force attracts them to each other. But what repulsive  force keeps them at some distance?

Discussed here.

Crudely, Fig 9, ωs  and ρs repel the nucleons at short distance, while σs and πs attract them at longer distances.

Also the strong nuclear force, which is repulsive at very short range.
